# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar

Tags: maven

When i try to build my first project using maven, i get the following exceptions

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:594)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:248)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.<clinit>(DbfFactory.java:208)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:893)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:653)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:322)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
25/09/2011 02:40:15 م org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:594)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:248)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.<clinit>(DbfFactory.java:208)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:893)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:653)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:322)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 15 more
25/09/2011 02:40:15 م org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
25/09/2011 02:40:15 م org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/spring_faces] startup failed due to previous errors
25/09/2011 02:40:16 م org.icefaces.impl.push.servlet.ICEpushResourceHandler notifyContextShutdown
INFO: MainServlet not found in application scope: java.lang.NullPointerException
25/09/2011 02:40:16 م com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:894)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:319)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:112)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4011)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4512)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
25/09/2011 02:40:16 م org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
25/09/2011 02:40:16 م org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
25/09/2011 02:40:16 م org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1@678fb397]) and a value of type [com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext] (value [com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@b57b39f]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
```

Comment: Please update the question with complete and correct information to avoid it being closed.

Answer (score 5):

Evidently, the stacktrace has nothing to do with maven. Instead it is the error deploying the web application.

Quoting from [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/j-users@xerces.apache.org/msg01235.html) possibly related discussion thread.

> You're probably picking up an incompatible mix of classes from Xerces 
>   2.8.1 and some old version of Xerces (something prior to 2.7.0) which
>   is  somewhere on your classpath or perhaps in the endorsed directory
>   of your  JDK 1.4 installation.