# Languagetool example: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar

Tags: java, maven, languagetool

The error message java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar
shows up when I try to run the example from

http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api

```java
JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
langTool.activateDefaultPatternRules();
List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check("A sentence " +
    "with a error in the Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy");

for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
  System.out.println("Potential error at line " +
      match.getLine() + ", column " +
      match.getColumn() + ": " + match.getMessage());
  System.out.println("Suggested correction: " +
      match.getSuggestedReplacements());
}
```

the solution offered in:
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545340/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-xerces-impl-xs-xmlschemaloader-loadgramm)

would mean that the Xerces specified in LanguageTools dependency would be the one creating the trouble.

`mvn dependency:tree | grep -i xerces`

does not show any result and in Languagetools pom.xml Xerces is explicitly excluded.

my own test project has the following xerces dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep -i xerces
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.tparty:xerces-impl:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
```

I assume I have do get rid of one of these dependencies, change the order of dependencies or add the correct xerces dependency for LanguageTool. What would be the right approach - one of these or something else?

Comment: The order of dependencies assumption seems to do the trick:  adding the xercesimpl 2.9.1 dependency as the first dependency <dependencies>
  <!-- Xerces latest version -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>xerces</groupId>
   <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to oracle documents This Error is

Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.